# My Boss belches all day, HELP

Tags: professionalism, work-environment

I work in a professional environment. My boss belches all day. The last time I asked him to be more polite about it he said "I'm in my own personal space" which is his office with the door open. My desk is just outside that door. It's getting to the point I'm going to go crazy as its such rudeness. This is affecting my work and my environment is very unpleasant. Also, I am not allowed to wear earphones so that's not an option. Please help me approach this before I explode. Thank you.

Comment: You said " last time I asked him to be more polite about it", which suggests to me you need to wait and see if they change their behaviour (regardless of how defensive they were).

Comment: "I'm sorry, but I'm a bit sensitive to sound.  Is it possible I could get another desk elsewhere in the office?"

Comment: @keshlam Why the hostility?

Comment: What exactly is the problem - the sound itself, his reaction to it, a suspicion that it might be deliberate, or deliberately exaggerated...?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that they aren't trying to be rude and there's a medical reason such as gastroesophageal reflux, aerophagia, or some other gastrointernal or digestive issue?

Comment: Apologies for the grumpy response, but honestly, this reads as a rant rather than a question. What do you want us to help you do, recognizing that you have no control over your boss and he may have no control over this either?

Comment: @iLuvLogix And that condition means they can't close the door?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Maybe they suffer from claustrophobia as well and like their office not to be confined by closed doors.. ;)

Comment: Ask your boss if you may allow to wear little earphones (NOT the big headphones). Tell him if you can listen to a little music, it will enhance your productivity. With the little music over small earphones, you still can hear people talking to you over your desk when they need you. -- Also, you can just wear 1 earphone on 1 ear while the other ear does not have the earphone. That may help to get your boss' approval for you to wear the earphone ?

Comment: Is your boss Asian? Are the belches purposeful or the biproduct of gastrointestinal distress?

It sounds that most likley your boss has some type of health issue.

Comment: Also, what did you say? Exact words please. If it was something similar to "you need to stop belching, its rude" then... there might have been a more diplomatic/better way to phrase it.

Comment: I don’t understand why nearly everyone in here are saying I am a snowflake, rude etc. I asked for advice for a genuine concern. No he isn’t claustrophobic no he does not have a condition, he is being a pig and an asshole. For example, If I comment I don’t like a certain song he plays it over and over. I can’t move my desk, small office and we are not allowed to wear earphones. Please I am not a whinger this is a genuine workplace problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your boss is inconsiderate for this problem, then he is significantly more inconsiderate for other problems. If you cannot find an easy fix of this issue there (e.g., wear some [**sound-muffling devices**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earplug) in your ears, or move to another desk), then find another job, where people have basic education.

Answer (score 5):

### Go to a doctor to see if you have misophonia.

Simply put, if you have a disability, you boss will be legally obligated to make reasonable accommodations for it. This might be closing his office door so that you can't hear his belching, allowing you to wear headphones or earplugs, or some similar accommodation.

Misophonia is a psychological condition that causes significant discomfort when you hear certain noises, such as belching.

It might be worthwhile for you to go visit a doctor, so they they can evaluate you for it. If you do have misophonia, them you can ask your doctor for a written diagnosis that you can present to your boss.